# GA3 Event Push Neccesary fields in Request

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-handling

I am trying to push a event towards GA3, mimicking an event done by a browser towards GA. From this Event I want to fill Custom Dimensions(visibile in the user explorer and relate them to a GA ID which has visited the website earlier). Could this be done without influencing website data too much? I want to enrich someone's data from an external source.

So far I cant seem to find the minimum fields which has to be in the event call for this to work. Ive got these so far:

```
v=1&
_v=j96d&
a=1620641575&
t=event&
_s=1&
sd=24-bit&
sr=2560x1440&
vp=510x1287&
je=0&_u=QACAAEAB~&
jid=&
gjid=&
_u=QACAAEAB~&
cid=GAID&
tid=UA-x&
_gid=GAID&
gtm=gtm&
z=355736517&
uip=1.2.3.4&
ea=x&
el=x&
ec=x&
ni=1&
cd1=GAID&
cd2=Companyx&
dl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.nl%2F&
ul=nl-nl&
de=UTF-8&
dt=example&
cd3=CEO
```

So far the Custom dimension fields dont get overwritten with new values. Who knows which is missing or can share a list of neccesary fields and example values?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things:

1. CD value will be overwritten only if in GA this CD's scope is set to the user-level. Make sure it is.
2. You need to know the client id of the user. You can confirm that you're having the right CID by using the user explorer in GA interface unless you track it in a CD. It allows filtering by client id.
3. You want to make this hit non-interactional, otherwise you're inflating the session number since G will generate sessions for normal hits. non-interactional hit would have `ni=1` among the params.
4. Wait. Scope calculations don't happen immediately in real-time. They happen later on. Give it two days and then check the results and re-conduct your experiment.
5. Use a throwaway/test/lower GA property to experiment. You don't want to affect the production data while not knowing exactly what you do.

There. A good use case for such an activity would be something like updating a life time value of existing users and wanting to enrich the data with it without waiting for all of them to come in. That's useful for targeting, attribution and more.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

1. This is the case. all CD's are user Scoped.
2. This is the case, we are collecting them.
3. ni=1 is within the parameters of each event call.
4. There are so many parameters, which parameters are neccesary?
5. we are using a test property for this.

We also got he Bot filtering checked out:
[Bot filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAwGX.png)

It's hard to test when the User Explorer has a delay of 2 days and we are still not sure which parameters to use and which not. Who could help on the parameter part? My only goal is to update de CD's on the person. Who knows which parameters need to be part of the event call?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).